# sinatra hello world app doesn't work

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm having trouble learning how to use Sinatra.

Versions are

- Mac OSX 10.11.2
- Ruby 2.2.2
- Sinatra 1.4.6

I wrote the same code as the first code in [this site](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html).

```
# main.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

Then I tried a command in the same derectory

```
% ruby main.rb
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with  backup from Thin 
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Then I accessed **http://localhost:4567** with Google Chrome, but the browser didn't recieve any data (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). Also nothing logged in Terminal.

I tried other port (like 3000) by -p option, but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it didn't work"* when you tried port 3000?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I see the the "hello world"

Comment: Very thanks for your immediate resonse, guys. _"it didn't work"_ meant that the browser showed nothing (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE again). I resolved by myself as the answer but I just updated gem two weeks ago... I can't tell what is the real cause.

Comment: _puts Sinatra::VERSION_ Use this to tell us which version of sinatra you are using

Answer (score 4):

I updated gem and reinstalled sinatra, then it worked.

```
gem update --system
gem uninstall sinatra
gem install sinatra
```